# Grouped bar chart for python data frame

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a grouped bar chart in python for a dataframe that looks like this:

| age | sex | target |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | m | 0 |
| 33 | f | 0 |
| 20 | m | 1 |
| 37 | f | 1 |
| 40 | f | 1 |

[this is what I want it to look like. One chart for sex and another chart for age. ][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgFUE.jpg

This is what I've tried so far but it didn't return what I wanted:

`df.groupby('sex')[target].value_counts().plot.bar(legend=True)`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value_counts()` alone will not suffice, you will need to `unstack()` it as well. Below is the updated code.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'age':[25,33,20,37,40], 'sex':['m','f','m','f','f'], 'target':[0,0,1,1,1]})
ax=df.groupby('sex')['target'].value_counts().unstack().plot.bar(legend=True, rot=0)
ax.set_yticks([0,1,2])
```

**Plot**

[image]

Comment: that worked perfectly thanks! Out of curiosity what does the set yticks do?

Comment: Great... It just sets the y-ticks to show only 0,1,2. Without it, think you will see 0,0.5,1,1,5,2 or something like that. As you pic just had 0,1,2 thought would set it. You can comment that line and check it out for yourself